# In this case, How to set uwsgi.ini?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, uwsgi

I will use uwsgi on AWS EC2 service.

I structured my server's workflow like this.

`Internet` - `ElasticLoadBalancer-a` - `webserver-nginx` - `ElasticLoadBalancer-b` - `web-application-django_uwsgi_server` - `RDS`

So between `webserver-nginx` and `web-application-django_uwsgi_server`, There will be communication through `http` data.

Also you should know that I run `web-application-django_uwsgi_server` on a docker container. Like, `docker run --name django_uwsgi -p 8080:8000 djangoproject_and_uwsgi:1.0`

And I set uwsgi ini file like this.

**uwsgi.ini in docker container:**

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /sampledir
wsgi-file          = /sampledir/sample/wsgi.py
master          = true
processes       = 10
# cron = -5 -1 -1 -1 -1 /path/to/some/script
harakiri=20
max-requests=5000
vacuum          = true
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
lazy-apps = true

# From this line, I ask these below options.
http = 0.0.0.0:8000
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
# socket          = /path/to/your/project/mysite.sock
# chmod-socket    = 664
```

I'm newbie in linux and network, but heard that socket settings will be better than just setting like `http = 8000`. Because of http overheads.

But I had `webserver-nginx` on another EC2 instance. In other words, `webserver-nginx` and `web-application-django_uwsgi_server` are not on the same EC2 instance(machine).

**QUESTION:**
In this case, How can I set `socket` or `port` settings appropriately?